# How to override RTL support on a layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I set `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml, but I need to force one of the views to be **left-to-right** (LTR) nonetheless, even when the language of the interface is Hebrew or Arabic. How can I force a specific view to be [LTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system#Directionality) in an [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_script) application?

Specifically, I want to force some linear layout to go left-to-right instead of the default right-to-left even when the language is right-to-left.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Generally `gravity="left"` is enough to force text to be left-to-right. But it didn't help with the direction of a linear layout. The solution was to add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">
```

for letf to right all layout content.

Answer (score 4):

To complete the answers, aside from XML, layout direction can also be changed programmatically with `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(view, LayoutDirection.RTL)`. This API can be used from API 19 and onwards, so If your min sdk version supports API below 19, an `if`-check needs to be performed:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force your application to LTR even on RTL languages you don't need layout direction (it works on an API level greater than 17) you can just set `android:supportsRtl` to false.

Comment: API level 17 is [Android 4.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1_Jelly_Bean) (Jelly Bean) (2012 vintage). Is that right?

Comment: @PeterMortensen based on  your link it's 4.2:D