# Override right-to-left in layouts

Tags: android, right-to-left

I have developed an application where everything is laid out left-to-right in its layouts and views. The issue is when I change the language in settings to Persian, a right-to-left language, everything changes to right-to-left.
How can I override this change to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Have you been using "start" and "end" tags in your Layouts instead of "left" and "right"? This will cause the behavior you described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override supportsRtl in one of the layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466048/override-supportsrtl-in-one-of-the-layouts)

Comment: If you want to disable Right to Left layout support then set android:supportRtl="false" in application tag of your manifest and if you want to support Right to Left layout then follow the instructions of Matei Radu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in this post:
[Override supportsRtl in one of the layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466048/override-supportsrtl-in-one-of-the-layouts)

you have to set

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply need to write this line inside the application Tag of your projects manifest

```
 android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Comment: Note this was added in API 17

Comment: that's okay , but OP not said he is using minSdk <17

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `android:toLeftOf` instead of `android:toStartOf`, and so forth if you are using RelativeLayout. Then the view is forced to the left regardless of locale